# How to add JTextField on a JButton just by clicking?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield

So I'm making something similar to tic-tac-toe using swing. I made a GridLayout and 9 buttons, and now i want one of my jbuttons to show the jtextfield when i click on it? I tried using MouseListener, but didn't manage to find a solution that way. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom button.

One way is to use a `CardLayout` for the button and add a `JTextField` and a `JLabel` to it. In the `ActionListener` of the button, if the button is pressed, you show the text field and disable the button. After you enter your text in the field and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>, the label with show, and the button is enabled.

[image][image][image]

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestButtonTextField {
    public TestButtonTextField() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new TextFieldButton("Hello"));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    protected class TextFieldButton extends JButton {

        private static final String FIELD = "field";
        private static final String LABEL = "label";

        private final CardLayout layout = new CardLayout();
        private final JLabel label;

        public TextFieldButton(String text) {
            super();
            setLayout(layout);

            label = new JLabel(text);
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            this.add(label, LABEL);

            final JTextField field = createField();
            this.add(field, FIELD);

            this.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    layout.show(TextFieldButton.this, FIELD);
                    TextFieldButton.this.setEnabled(false);
                }
            });

        }

        private JTextField createField() {
            final JTextField field = new JTextField(5);
            field.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    label.setText(field.getText());
                    field.setText("");
                    layout.show(TextFieldButton.this, LABEL);
                    TextFieldButton.this.setEnabled(true);
                }
            });
            return field;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                new TestButtonTextField();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use addActionListener to add a suitable listener to the button. You can toggle the visibility of a component using the *setVisible(boolean)* method. However, you probably have to resize/repaint the window after this action.

Edit: If you want to replace the whole window content, you might also want to take a look at Swing's CardLayout: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html

Comment: I don't want to replace the whole window content. Just to fill the button with some strings on click. It didn't work even with _setVisible(true)_ .Kinda stuck on this.

Comment: Do you want to show the JTextField or fill the button? Do you want to react on a button click or on a click on the text field? Not sure that I understand what you want to do.

Comment: I want a JTextField to appear on top of the JButton, when i click on it (JButton), in order to type in a String which I can maybe save or something (I'll deal with the usage of that later, as soon as i get passed this)

Comment: Still not sure whether this is what you want, but: 1) create the textfield, but set the visibility to false; 2) add an ActionListener to the button. The action listener sets the visibility of the textfield to true and repaints/resizes the window.